# Improving spanned/spannable performance in setting TextView RecylcerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, textview, spannable

I have a `RecyclerView` with a number of `TextViews`.  One of these `TextViews` is populated with a `Spanned`, via a marked up `String` taken from an `ArrayList<Object>`.  After reading [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/underspanding-spans-1b91008b97e4) tutorial by Florina Muntenescu, I realize I can likely improve my performance by using `Spannable Factory`.  My biggest problem is that her code is written in `Kotlin` (and I'm not quite there yet).

As far as I can tell, this is the key information,

> Let’s say that we want to reuse a `TextView` and set the text multiple times, like in a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`...

```
val spannableFactory = object : Spannable.Factory() {
    override fun newSpannable(source: CharSequence?): Spannable {
        return source as Spannable
    }
}`
```

> Set the `Spannable.Factory` object once right after you get a
>   reference to your TextView. If you’re using a RecyclerView, do this
>   when you first inflate your views.

```
textView.setSpannableFactory(spannableFactory)
```

So, suppose I have this simple `RecyclerView adapter` setting a single `Spanned` `TextView`.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder rvh, int position){

    String string =arrayList.get(position).getValue();
    Spanned spanned = getSpannedValue(string);
    rvh.tv.setText(spanned);
}
```

How can I change my code to utilize the recommendation from Florina?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java you should just override method `newSpannable`, in its implementation cast source (CharSequence) to Spannable and set this factory to `TextView` (tvText in my case)

```
       tvText.setSpannableFactory(new Spannable.Factory(){
            @Override
            public Spannable newSpannable(CharSequence source) {
                return (Spannable) source;
            }
        });
```

Keep in mind, it should be **set** from `ViewHolder's` constructor, **not** `onBindViewHolder`. When you get reference to it by `findViewById`.

Comment: Thanks, so I findViewByID, then add your code, then setText... all in ViewHolder.  Correct?

Comment: Oops, I meant  so I findViewByID, then add your code... in ViewHolde constructor.  And setText in onBIndViewHolder

Comment: Where should we write setSpan? How does SpannableFactory reduce the number of object creation?

Comment: By creating the spannable factory inside setSpannableFactory, we are creating a new factory every time we create a view holder. I'd say it's better to create the factory only once in a global variable and use that variable to set the factory.